# Is generating CSRF token on the front-end a bad idea?

Tags: django, csrf

In Django world, CSRF token is generated in a way that doesn't involve any information known only to the server. It's perfectly possible to generate a valid CSRF token in javascript - Django will happily accept it.

In particular, one could have a piece of javascript that generates valid CSRF token and sets it as a cookie (and it will work fine because of the same origin).

Are there any security related drawbacks of doing that? The only thing I can think of is that such cookie cannot have the http-only flag set (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**

CSRF is a solution to restrict CSRF attacks. So in the server, a code is generated (and signed) to check is user using built-in js codes or not. for example, a user can call a function without CSRF protection in the browser console or with a browser extension or with curl without any browser, in this condition, you cannot understand is user knows this function call or not!

On the other side, you want to make a new CSRFTOKEN and send it to the server with ajax and this service cannot protect with CSRF. So the hackers can use this ajax call for CSRF forgery! And the hacker can find your CSRF maker code in your js libraries.

For your Idea, you can use some user info and save it in session info such as use-agent, client-IP, and ...

Comment: "And the hacker can find your CSRF maker code in your js libraries." - 
This is also true for django code - anyone can read that (as it's open source) and generate a CSRF token that is valid (using any language if thye adapt the code).

Comment: CSRF made from security code were generated for each project in creation.